# How does Activiti achieve scalability

Tags: activiti

Can anyone describe how Activiti scales? I'm particularly interested in where application state resides and how the database can be scaled (horizontally/vertically). Are there any single points of synchronisation?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this post here: http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-jbpm/activiti-bpmn/clustering-activiti-bpmn

Tijs Rademakers, project lead of Activiti, speaks about those topics in this interview.